# How to get screen resolution of an android device using LIBGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working android game development and I am new in it.
I want to develop a game which screen resolution free. It will be enough for me if i get to know that how to catch screen resolution of an android device using libgdx library.
After some googling i read the following code on different sites, but it is not for libgdx.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Except this i also used technique given on the following website that used "OrthographicCamera" class for solving the problem, and didn't work for me either.

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.0

How can i get the screen resolution or any way to adjust screen resolution for my game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though there are some answers here on my question. This is what exactly worked for me. I had to add 'app' after 'Gdx' for it to work.

```
Gdx.app.graphics.getWidth(); 
Gdx.app.graphics.getHeight();
```

Comment: So you copy answers from others and accept your answer for brownie points?

Comment: @Muhmmand, Lestat answered the question on 12th, your comment to that post shows that you got the solution from his answer. So no, accepting your own answer is naive.

Answer (score 101):

```
Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

:)

Comment: Gdx.app.graphics.getWidth();
Gdx.app.graphics.getHeight(); 

this is what worked for me :)

Comment: Nice :) If this answer helped you, could you accept it. Thanks :3

Comment: Well, since he needed to add "app" in there, your answer kind of didn't sort it out. You could edit your answer and maybe then?

Comment: @SteveWaters he doesn't need to add .app though :)

Answer (score 10):

ok you can get the screen resolution by this

```
Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
```

//for screen width

```
Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

//for screen height

and if you want to make a screen resolution free game you can set the view port like this

```
float scrw=320;

float scrh=480;
```

scrw is [viewport's](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) width and scrh is viewport's height

and set the camera to

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, scrw, scrh);
camera.update();
```

Comment: what does that viewport make? how does it works? do you have an url for noobs as me?

Answer (score 5):

In the newer LibGDX release, the code is now

```
int width = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
int height = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

works for me.